# regex to remove characters at end of word only - js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove exclamation marks at the end of a word.

eg. `remove("!!!Hi !!hi!!! !hi") === "!!!Hi !!hi !hi"`

I am able to remove all exclamation marks, but am unable to target those just at the end of a word.

The following is what I currently have.

```
function remove(s){
  return s.replace(/([a-z]+)[!]/ig, '$1');
}
```

Comment: I think you may use [`.replace(/\b!+\B/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/ugHixG/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can strip off `!`s that are at the end of words using the following RegExp:

```
"!!!Hi !!hi!!! !hi"
  .replace(/!+\s/g, ' ')  // this removes it from end of words
  .replace(/!+$/g, '')    // this removes it from the end of the last word
```

Result: `"!!!Hi !!hi !hi"`

Answer (score 1):

You cant try this one:

```
\b!+
```

It matches `!` that follows a word.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to:

```
/([a-z]+)!+/ig
```

Then

```
function remove(s){
  return s.replace(/([a-z]+)!+/ig, '$1');
}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex

```js
console.log("!!!Hi !!hi!!! !hi!!!".replace(/([a-z]+)[!]+/ig, '$1'))
```

Comment: This is [a copy of @idmean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45320428/3832970) with no added value.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier not to use regex, but insted use lastIndexOf and slice

something like:

```
function removeQuestionmark(inputvalue) {
  var index = inputValue.lastIndexOf("!");

  if(inputValue.endsWith("!"))
    return inputvalue.slice(0,index-1);

  return `${inputvalue.slice(0,index-1)${inputValue.slice(index+1)}}
}
```

I have not tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should add a + so you take more than one !

```
function remove(s){

    return s.replace(/([a-z]+)([!]+)/ig, "$1");
}
```